# Select first occurrence of value after last occurrence of other value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to find the current operation of a part. The table I have to get this information from lists operation statuses of complete (1) or 0.  So the table typically looks like:

```
ID  Operation  Status

 1      100      1
 2      200      1
 3      250      1
 4      300      0
 5      350      0
```

So in this case Operation 300 is the current op which I get using MIN(Operation) WHERE Status = 0.

However, some cases have appeared where some operations are skipped which would look like:

```
ID  Operation  Status

 1     100       1
 2     200       0
 3     250       1
 4     300       0
 5     350       0
```

So in this case the current operation is still Operation 300 but MIN(Operation) doesn't work.  What I need is the first occurrence of the row where Status = 0 that follows the last occurrence of a Status = 1 row.  How could I achieve this?

Edit:  Also have to consider the case where all operations are Status 0, where the correct result would be the first row (Operation 100)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Can't you just get the max when status = 1, then get the minimum value which is greater than that?

Comment: I forgot the case where all statuses are 0. In this case I would need the correct result to be the first row (operation 100). I edited the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the entire row to work with:

```sql
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
    ID INT,
    Operation INT,
    Status BIT
);

INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
     (1, 100, 1)
    ,(2, 200, 0)
    ,(3, 250, 1)
    ,(4, 300, 0)
    ,(5, 350, 0)
;

WITH MaxOperation AS (
    SELECT MAX(x.Operation) AS MaxOperation
    FROM @MyTable x
    WHERE x.Status = 1
)
SELECT TOP 1 t.*
FROM @MyTable t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT MaxOperation FROM MaxOperation) x
WHERE t.Operation > x.MaxOperation
    OR x.MaxOperation IS NULL
ORDER BY t.Operation
```

This will result in:

```
ID          Operation   Status
----------- ----------- ------
4           300         0
```

It will also produce this if all the `Status` values are `0`:

```
ID          Operation   Status
----------- ----------- ------
1           100         0
```

Comment: For the second data set the correct record would be the one with and ID of 2 I believe

Comment: @AlanBurstein OP states that the for the 2nd dataset "the current operation is still Operation 300"

Comment: Yep - I just re-read the OP. Good solution.

Comment: I forgot the case where all statuses are 0.  In this case I would need the correct result to be the first row (operation 100).  I edited the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a clever window function way to do it, but in vanilla sql this is the idea

```
SELECT MIN(Operation)
  FROM SOME_TABLE
 WHERE Operation > 
         ( SELECT MAX(Operation)
             FROM SOME_TABLE
            WHERE status = 1
         )
```

Comment: This still returns 300 given for the second data set which is not correct.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I misread the question and thought he was looking for the first status = 0 which didn't go back to 1.

Comment: @AlanBurstein I don't know, I read it again and think this is at least how the verbiage reads. Whether that's the intention ... dunno

Comment: Not that clever, just a `LEAD(Status) OVER (ORDER BY Operation DESC)`

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by user Error_2646, a good way would be something like

```
select
    min(ID)
from
    [YourTable]
where
    ID > (select max(ID) from [YourTable] where Status = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer will give you the correct answer.  If you can add the  expected output in a image it is more easy to identify what you need. Please add schema and data when, so that it is easy for user to put their solutions.

```
Schema and data I used:
( 
 ID INT 
 ,operation INT
 ,Status INT 
 )

 insert into  Occurances values(1,100,1)
 insert into  Occurances values(2,200,0)
 insert into  Occurances values(1,250,1)
 insert into  Occurances values(1,300,0)
 insert into  Occurances values(1,350,0)

 SELECT *
 FROM
 (
    SELECT 
    Rank() OVER ( ORDER BY  operation) AS [rank]
    ,MIN([operation]) AS  [min] 
    ,id
    ,[status]
 FROM Occurances
 WHERE [Status]= 0
 GROUP BY  id
    ,[status]
    ,operation
 UNION  
  SELECT 
    Rank() OVER ( ORDER BY  operation DESC) AS [rank]
   ,MAX([operation]) AS  [min] 
   ,id
   ,[status]
 FROM Occurances
 WHERE [Status]= 1
 GROUP BY  id
      ,[status]
      ,operation

 ) AS A
 WHERE A.[rank]= 1
```

This is the answer I am getting:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very efficiently with a window function:

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM (
    SELECT *, LEAD(Status) OVER (ORDER BY Operation DESC) AS PreviousStatus
    FROM myTable
)
WHERE Status = 0 AND PreviousStatus = 1
ORDER BY Operation DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
        (
                ID          int
            ,   Operation   int
            ,   [Status]    bit
        )
;

INSERT INTO @Table (ID, Operation,  [Status])
    VALUES
                (1, 100, 1)
            ,   (2, 200, 0)
            ,   (3, 250, 1)
            ,   (4, 300, 1)
            ,   (5, 350, 0)
;

SELECT  TOP 1 T.*
FROM    @Table T
WHERE   T.[Status] = 0
    AND T.ID    >   (
                        SELECT  TOP 1 T.ID
                        FROM    @Table  T
                        WHERE   T.[Status] = 1
                        ORDER BY ID DESC
                    )   
ORDER BY    ID
```